# <g:textField> Only perform onclick if field is blank

Tags: grails, groovy

I was wondering if anyone could help me out with an issue I'm having in Grails.
I have a method that is performed if a user clicks on a read only g:textField which populates the field with the current username, but I need the method to only be performed if the textField is blank so that one user cannot override another users username if they already put one in.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given

```
<input type="text" value="whatever" id="name"/>
```

This jQuery script should do it

```
$('#name').click(function() {

  if (!$(this).val()) {
    var name = // send an AJAX request to get the username
    $(this).val(name);
  }
});
```

Of course you would also need to check on the server side that the username is blank

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're managing the click with javascript, you just need to check if there is a value there or not.

Warning: Untested jQuery pseudo code ahead:

```
$("#textField").on("click", function() {
  var $element = $(this);
  var value = $element.val();

  if (!value || $.trim(value).length == 0) {
    // populate the text field with a username
  }

});
```